# shell script "if" test is not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

A="Message Agent is not buffering."
command > file
Buffering_status=`/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[()\t:-]' '{print $NF}' file|sed '/^$/d'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{$1=$1}1'|uniq -u|tail -1`

agent_status_count=`/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[()\t:-]' '{print $NF}' file|sed '/^$/d'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{$1=$1}1'|sed '$d'|sort -u|wc -l`
echo $Buffering_status $agent_status_count

if [[ $A == $Buffering_status  &&  $agent_status_count == 1 ]]
then

echo "executing fine part"

else

echo $Buffering_status $agent_status_count
echo "something wrong"

fi
```

Debugging output:

```
+ A='Message Agent is not buffering.'
+ command
++ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[()\t:-]' '{print $NF}' file
++ sed '/^$/d'
++ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{$1=$1}1'
++ uniq -u
++ tail -1
+ Buffering_status='Message Agent is not buffering.'
++ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '[()\t:-]' '{print $NF}' file
++ sed '/^$/d'
++ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{$1=$1}1'
++ sed '$d'
++ sort -u
++ wc -l
+ agent_status_count='       1'
+ echo Message Agent is not buffering. 1
Message Agent is not buffering. 1
+ [[ Message Agent is not buffering. == Message Agent is not buffering. ]]
+ [[        1 == 1 ]]
+ echo Message Agent is not buffering. 1
Message Agent is not buffering. 1
+ echo 'something wrong'
something wrong
```

Comment: Your `$agent_status_count` variable is not `"1"` but `"    1"` (note the spaces). Comparing `"1"` and `"     1"` will lead to false.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is string comparison, and as kba pointed out, "1" is not the same string as " 1". The `-eq` operator will do what you want.

...

```
if [[ $A == $Buffering_status  &&  $agent_status_count -eq 1 ]]
```

...